# Removing the "%" encoding in URL string

Tags: php, url, decoding

I am attempting to open a page with `window.open` and it's not working. The path shown is like `xyz/a%20b%20c%20.pdf`, but it is supposed to be `xyz/abc.pdf`. If I remove the `%` and `20` manually, it works, how can I remove these characters using PHP?

Comment: Why would you want to remove that?  It is proper URI character entity encoding making your URI valid, where it might not be valid otherwise and certainly less stable.

Answer (score 7):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   urldecode — Decodes URL-encoded string
>
> **Description**
>
> string urldecode ( `string $str` )
>   Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.

#### Example

```
echo urldecode('xyz/a%20b%20c%20.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as URL Encoding. You need to decode the string. If you are using jQuery you should check out the [URL Encode](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode) plug in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to urldecode (as stated above).

However, you say that you can remove the %20 and it will work. I would say you need them, they decode to spaces. Check it out using this online url decoder:

http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/UrlDecode

it decodes to:

xyz/a b c .pdf

not

xyz/abc.pdf